# Ignore the last delimeter in java string tokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a string like this "AddUser_test_NewUserForm_singinprocess".

By using the java string tokenizer, i want the output like this:

Adduser

test

NewUserForm_singinprocess

The delemeter is " _ " and my main target is to ignore the last " _ " in " NewUserForm_singinprocess " as a delimeter.

how i can do this ?

Comment: Can you use regex and `String#split()`?

Comment: if you don't put any code we wont be able to reproduce your problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String strWithDelimeter = "Hello_Hi_Good_Morning";

    StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(strWithDelimeter, "_");
    int noOfToken = strToken.countTokens();
    int count =1;
    String currentElement = null, lastElement = null,lastElement2 = null;
    while(strToken.hasMoreTokens()) {
        currentElement = strToken.nextToken().toString();
        if(count == noOfToken)
            lastElement = currentElement;
        else if(count == noOfToken-1)
            lastElement2 = currentElement;
        else 
            System.out.println(currentElement);
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(lastElement2+"_"+lastElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String#split()` to achieve this easily :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String s = "AddUser_test_NewUserForm_singinprocess";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("_(?=.*_)")));
}
```

O/P :

```
[AddUser, test, NewUserForm_singinprocess]
```